# Сортировка матрицы массивом указателей

Tags: c++, visual-c++, указатели

Вот две функции из моего кода,в перовой динамический двумерный массив удаляется, во второй сортируется первый столбец, проблема следующая:

```
void deleteSqMatr(int **&matr, int sz)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
        delete[] matr[i];
    delete[] matr;
    matr = NULL;
}

void sortCol(int **matr, int sz, int col = 0)
{
    int **p = new int*[sz];
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        p[i] = &matr[i][col];

    for (int i = 0; i < sz - 1; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < sz - i - 1; j++)
            if (*p[j] > *p[j + 1])
            {
                int temp = *p[j];
                *p[j] = *p[j + 1];
                *p[j + 1] = temp;
            }
}
```

Возникает ошибка "нарушение прав доступа чтения по адресу...", при чем возникает она через раз в функции удаления матрицы. Я полностью уверен, что что-то ни так в сортировке столбца, а вернее там где я меняю местами указатели, потому что если переписать обычным способом `int temp = matr[j][0]; matr[j][0] = matr[j+1][0]; matr[j+1][0] = temp;` то ошибок никаких не возникает. Я думал, что там как-то адреса смещаются, но перед функцией удаления так же вызывается функция вывода на экран, и там всё в порядке. Подскажите, почему мой код неправильно отрабатывает, заранее спасибо!

Comment: Пока функция sortCol  не использована, нет  ошибки, а когда вы ее начнете использовать...  Если даже вы исправите наивное сравнение  (int i = 0; i < 9; i++  то всеравно не отсортируете массив, поскольку вы сортируете другой массив  р, который нигде не сможете использовать и только займете память в куче, а освобождать не сможете никак...

Comment: Что такое `9` в первом цикле и откуда оно взялось? Везде используется `sz`, а здесь вдруг какое-то `9`.

Comment: Как раз наоборот, она мне отсортировала столбец оригинального массива, так как я оперирую адресами оригинального массива. Ошибка как раз была в той опечатке с девяткой, там поставил до `sz` и ошибка пропадает. Я выходил за пределы своего массива. 
А память от массива указателей я очищаю таким образом:
`for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
  p[i] = NULL;
delete[] p;`
Глупее ошибки и быть не могло, спасибо

Comment: @Tilivali: С какой целью вам понадобилось перед удалением `p` проходить по его элементам и обнулять их? В чем смысл этого обнуления?

Comment: @AnT: Разве если их не обнулять, адреса которые они хранят исчезнут с их удаление? На сколько я понимаю ситуация такая же как и с двумерным динамическим массивом, то есть при удалении сначала проходимся по каждому `*p`, а потом удаляем и сам `**p`. Или я не прав?

Comment: @Tilivali: Не понимаю, о чем вы говорите. "Адреса исчезнут"? Что это значит? Если вы удаляете блок памяти, все, что он хранит, исчезнет вместе с ним. Когда вы удаляете `matr`, вы же не обнуляете `matr[i]`. Зачем вы здесь взялись что-то обнулять?

Comment: @AnT: Я имею ввиду, что например указатель `p[0]` хранит адрес ячейки `matr[0][0]`, а указатель `p` хранит адрес ячейки `p[0]`. Если мы удалим `delete[] p`, то удалится и значение, которое хранит `p[0]` в памяти или нужно предварительно `p[0]` обнулить, чтобы его значение не осталось в памяти?

Comment: @ExsaNik: Нет, ничего обнулять предварительно не надо. То, что вы делаете - это классическое "выкрасить и выбросить".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка была в опечатке в этом цикле `for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)`
Там никакой `9` быть не может, там должно быть `sz` `for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)`
Вопрос исчерпан, всем спасибо.